# Excel: Flag records that have a the same value across rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have data with a column for `organisation code`, a `cost code` and  associated `cost value`.

Each organisation has up to **8** cost codes, each with a cost value.

The data is arranged as on the attached example:

[image]

I need to create a variable, where I flag with a **1**, those  *organisations* where each of their *cost values* are the same for each of their *cost codes*.

I have sorted the data on the organisation code and cost value, so I can check the if the previous value is identical for the subsequent value for each organisation but I need to check, if all the cost values for each cost code for a given organisation is the same.

Comment: You mean to say if Cost code from 1 to 8 has similar Cost value then Variable will be 1. As you have shown in the example Cost value 4 for all Cost codes.

Comment: yes that's right, if it is the same cost value, then I new variable will be 1

Answer (score 2):

In this example the sample data is in cells C3:E14. Now in cell F3 put the following formula and from within the formula bar press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to create an Array Formula. The formula shall be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an array formula.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$14=C3)*1)=SUMPRODUCT((IF($C$3:$C$14=C3,$E$3:$E$14)=E3)*1),"1","0")
```

[image]

Comment: I landed little late with the Answer,, @pat2015 already fixed the problem.